# Android Process

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using this code for POST and is woking ok. As I'm calling this from ManinActivity, would like to have the response as a String to be returned. Tried to put String instead of void but where ever I place return response, it is giving error.

```
private void addRecordToSheet() {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Record","Please wait");
    
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "MyURL",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String **response**) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
            
            parmas.put("action","addRecord");
            parmas.put("eMail",reMail);
            parmas.put("id", rID);
            parmas.put("Name",reName);
            parmas.put("Phone", rMobile);
            return parmas;
        }
    };

    int socketTimeOut = 50000;
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: Unable to put this code in that format. Can you please help?

Comment: In addition, I need to have this as a synchronous task. The link provides solution for making my task Asynchronous.